# Up and downgrading node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to upgrade node.js to test out some stuf and then downgrade it again.

Is it safe to upgrade by downloading the latest release on

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

and then downgrade to an older version from here ?

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

I am running windows 10.

Comment: If this is for local development, you may try nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for this stuff, I think it's the best when you want to change node versions on the fly. Not sure about windows support, tho.

Answer (score 1):

In order to manage multiple installations of node.js on a Windows computer you can use one of:

*nvm-windows*:
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

*nodist*:
https://github.com/nullivex/nodist

Answer (score 0):

You can use n

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

If you use n, you only need to type n "node_version", or n "node_version" LTS, to change your node version

Comment: [n does not work on Windows at the moment.](https://github.com/tj/n#additional-details)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you verify that it works flawlessly ?